# Design and Implementation of scalable services

Tags: architecture, activemq-classic, scalability, distributed, bigdata

We have written agents deployed/distributed across the network. Agents sends data every 15 Secs may be even 5 secs. Working on a service/system to which all agent can post data/tuples with marginal payload. Upto 5% drop rate is acceptable. Ultimately the data will be segregated and stored into DBMS System (currently we are using MSQL).

Question(s) I am looking for answer

1. Client/Server Communication: Agent(s) can post data. Status of sending data is not that important. But there is a remote where Agent(s) to be notified if the server side system generates an event based on the data sent.

   - Lot of advices from internet suggests using Message Bus (ActiveMQ) for async communication. Multicast and UDP are the alternatives.
2. Persistence: After some evaluation data to be stored in DBMS System.

   - End of processing data is an aggregated record for which MySql looks scalable. But on the volume of data is exponential. Considering HBase as an option.

Looking if there are any alternatives for above two scenarios and get expert advice.

Answer (score 0):

1. Async is good option. Develop 2 modules: frontend - for fast post data with some of kind queus (for caching) and backend - with event generator and storing to DB
2. Use DB closes to operating system (minimal overhead, I think transaction not needed) and with non blocking (optimistic locking) caching, async caching. For example: DB Berkeley or write data into small files and make second async process which will be read data and store to DB.